# How are EE templates and entries tied together?

Tags: ee3

I am new to EE and am trying to help maintain an large, old EE installation (Running EE 3.3.3 on IIS).  It uses the Construct plugin.

There is an entry on the site with slug “business-office”, and I have a template html file in the backend named boffice.html. Changes made in boffice.html show up on the site on entry “business-office”. This template is specific to this one entry. There are many entries on the site with this same 1-to-1 setup.  All good so far.

What I don’t understand, and haven’t been able to discover, is how the template and entry are connected -- how does EE know to use that template with that entry? I don’t see anything in the entry options for “business-office” to specify a template. In the template code, nothing points back to a particular entry.  In Template manager, I can see a “site/boffice” template listed, but it doesn’t specify “business-office” in any way that I can see. In Template Routes, the route is empty for “site/boffice”.  In the Construct plugin, I see a similar template entry to the EE template, presumably to tie together the EE template to the Construct template (?), but again, no direct reference to “business-office”.

How does EE know to use the boffice.html template with the “business-office” entry?

Comment: Do your templates contain a `{exp:channel:entries` tag? If that doesn't specify a url_title or entry_id, then it's likely using the `dynamic` feature to determine which entry to load - https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/entries.html#dynamic. A more standard way to do this is by defining either the `url_title` or `entry_id` parameters on the channel entries tag so it's more apparent in your template which entry will be displayed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This association can be set while editing the Construct navigation/tree settings for the menu node which corresponds to the entry.

[image]